# Find polynomials $M_1(x)$ and $M_2(x)$ such that $(x+1)^2M_1(x) + (x^2 + x + 1)M_2(x) = 1$

Tags: polynomials

I have been trying to solve this with no success. Could you suggest me a solution?

Comment: I think you can do this using the extended Euclidean algorithm for polynomials.

Comment: For clarity, are you working over $\mathbb{Z}(x)$ or e.g. a polynomial field over $C_2$? (Though in any case, the Euclidean algorithm is the way to go)

Comment: Extended Euclidean algorithm plus [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Comment: By comparing it's easy to see degree of $M_1(x)$ and $M_2(x)$ are equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back to the basics! Remember how you do it for integers? For example, how would you find $x$, $y$ such that $23x+47y=1$? That's right, Euclid's algorithm.

Let's try to calculate the GCD of $(x+1)^2$ and $x^2+x+1$.

$$
(x+1)^2 - (x^2+x+1) = x\\
(x^2+x+1) - x(x+1) = 1
$$
Hence,
$$(x^2+x+1) - ((x+1)^2 - (x^2+x+1))(x+1) = 1$$
Therefore,
$$- (x+1)(x+1)^2 + (x+2)(x^2+x+1) = 1$$

Comment: Okay, as I understand, here you replaced x with $(x+1)^2 - (x^2+x+1)$.$(x^2+x+1) - ((x+1)^2 - (x^2+x+1))(x+1) = 1$. But why? This should be part of a specific algorithm and I can't find a pattern. for example, what would be the equivalent to these steps in case of 23x + 47y = 1? P.S. I know how Euclid's algorithm works generally.

Comment: Maybe $23x+47y=1$ is not a good example because it's just $(x,y)=(-2,1)$, so let's say $23x+30y=1$.
$$
30-23=7\\
23 - 3\cdot7=2\\
7 - 3\cdot2=1
$$
Then we can work backwards, substituting the equations into each other, until we've got a linear combination of $23$ and $30$. The first step would be $7 - 3\cdot(23-3\cdot7)=1$. Do you see how that finishes?

Comment: ohhh I think I got it. Basically we say that $a = q_1b + r_1$; $b = q_2r_1 + r_2$; $r_1 = q_3r_2 + r_3$ and so on until we reach $r_{k-1} = q_{k+1}r_k$. so by substituting b and $r_1$ we solve the problem. Now I remember there was a ready result of the substitution in my book. Thanks!

Comment: thanks! I got it and just solved the problem.

Comment: @vrugtehagel What does 'you can't always do this for polynomials' mean here? This usual 'extended' Euclidean algorithm should be guaranteed to generate a pair $a(), b()$ that satisfies $a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x)=\mathop{GCD}(f(x), g(x))$...

Comment: I'll just flat out admit I haven't done some proper math in ages and I came back here for some nostalgia - clearly I'm more rusty than I thought I was. I remember something that was different about polynomials with integer coefficients, like e.g. $M_1(x) = x^2$ and $M_2(x) = 2x + 1$, but I guess even then this works to some extent. I'll remove that part, thanks for calling me out!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate basic approach based upon coefficient comparison of polynomials. We are looking for polynomials $M_1(x), M_2(x)$ so that the identity
\begin{align*}
\left(x^2+2x+1\right)M_1(x)+\left(x^2+x+1\right)M_2(x)=1\tag{1}
\end{align*}
is valid.

We start with some observations:

- Since the right-hand side of (1) is a polynomial of degree zero, the left-hand side has also to be a polynomial of degree zero.
- We are looking for polynomials $M_1$ and $M_2$ which have smallest possible degree. We observe setting $M_1(x)=1$ and $M_2(x)=-1$ is not appropriate since we get rid of the square terms but not of the linear terms.
- **Ansatz:** We start with *linear* polynomials
  \begin{align*}
  M_1(x)=ax+b\qquad M_2(x)=cx+d
  \end{align*}
  with unknown coefficients $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$, multiply out and make a comparison of coefficients of LHS and RHS of (1).

We denote with $[x^n]$ the coefficient of $x^n$ of a polynomial and obtain from (1)
\begin{align*}
[x^3]:\qquad\qquad &a+c&=0\\
[x^2]:\qquad\qquad&(2a+b)+(c+d)&=0\\
[x^1]:\qquad\qquad&(a+2b)+(c+d)&=0\\
[x^0]:\qquad\qquad&b+d&=1\\
\end{align*}

Coefficient comparison of $[x^3]$ gives: $c=-a$. Putting this in the other three equations results in

\begin{align*}
a+b+d&=0\\
2b+d&=0\\
b+d&=1\\
\end{align*}
from which we easily find $a=-1, b=-1, c=1, d=2$.

> We finally obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{M_1(x)=-x-1\quad M_2(x)=x+2}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with the other given answer.